# Trouble getting fragmentContainer to work in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am developing an app in android studio which includes a `fragmentContainer` that I can't seem to get to work. I just get an error saying:

```
Error:(20, 53) error: cannot find symbol variable fragmentContainer
```

The code is as follows:

```
package criminalintent.android.bignerdranch.com.criminalintentnew;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

/**
 * This is the view-class. This Class is getting with the CrimeFragment controller.
 */

public class CrimeActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);
    // Organize fragment addition to main UI :
        FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer); // this is where it starts to mention the error. 

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new CrimeFragment();

            fragManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit(); // also shows up as error. 
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure fragmentContainer is defined correctly in activity.xml or layoutName.xml

Comment: Thanks! This was the issue.